# Remove words (letters followed by space) from a specific column

Tags: text-processing, awk, grep, regular-expression

I have a file and the format is as follows:

```
cat dog AHF123432 | 123432 | dhfshfjdh
lion  AFG23412 |23412 | dfshjhfjdhj
```

I need to remove those words from first column which contains only alphabets i.e., cat(followed by space) and dog from first row 
and lion from the second row

My output will look something like:

```
AHF123432 | 123432 |  dhfshfjdh    
AFG23412 | 23412 | dhfshfjdh
```

Comment: what did you try? Do you have some regular expression?

Comment: Hi Jakuje. I'm a newbie to Linux. I tried with cut grep and awk.
cut -d' ' -f2-
grep -Ev  '^[a-zA-Z]\>'
awk '$1 !~ /[a-zA-Z]/'
But nothing worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This removes all pure-alphabetic words from the beginning of the line:

```
$ sed -r 's/^([[:alpha:]]* )*//' filename.tsv
AHF123432 | 123432 | dhfshfjdh
AFG23412 |23412 | dfshjhfjdhj
```

Or, to save the output in a new file:

```
sed -r 's/^([[:alpha:]]* )*//' filename.tsv > final.tsv
```

#### How it works

- `[[:alpha:]]*` matches any number of alphabetic characters followed by a space.  In other words, it matches a word followed by a space.

  In more detail, `[[:alpha:]]` matches a single alphabetic character.  ``[[:alpha:]]*` matches any number of such characters.
- `([[:alpha:]]* )*` matches any number of such words followed by spaces.
- `^([[:alpha:]]* )*` matches any any number of words followed by spaces but, because of the `^`, only starting from the beginning of the line.
- The substitute command removes all those matching words.  The substitute command has the form `s/old/new/` where, here, `old` is our expression above which matches any number of words starting from the beginning of the line.  We want to replace these words with nothing so, here, we use the empty string for `new`.

In olden times, the regular expression to match an alphabetic characters was `[a-zA-Z]`.  With modern unicode fonts, that is now longer reliable.  Because our regular expression above uses `[:alpha:]`, it is unicode-safe.

Comment: Hi John, I tried your answer, but an error states -E invalid option..

Comment: `-E` works on BSD sed and the  newer GNU sed versions.   Try `-r` instead.  Answer updated.

Comment: I'm working on PUTTY.

Comment: OK.  Please try with `-r` as in the updated answer.   (PUTTY is communication system.  If `-r` doesn't work either, it would be helpful to know what operating system is on the other end of the PUTTY communication channel.)

Comment: Hi John, with -r option. The output looks like this:
dog AHF123432 | 123432 | dhfshfjdh
lion AFG23412 |23412 | dfshjhfjdhj
Only the cat from the first row is removed. Rest all remains the same

Comment: When I opened the output file in VI Editor. I m able to see something like Dog^M AHF123432 | 123432 | dhfshfjdh. I think because of ^M its not working.

Comment: Good detective work! The `^M` characters can cause all kinds of strange trouble.  I recommend getting rid of them first.  Use, for example: `tr -d '\r' <filename.tsv >fixed.tsv`.

Answer (score 0):

If your `grep` supports `p`erl `c`ompatible `r`egular `e`xpressions:

```
grep -Po '^([a-z]* +)*\K.*'
```

or

```
pcregrep -o '^([a-z]* +)*\K.*'
```

Comment: Hi Jimmij, sorry to say.. dint work.. Let me know if this is correct way:
pcregrep -o '^([a-z]* +)+\K.*' filename.tsv > final.tsv

Comment: @frozen_dreams what's the output of `grep --version`, `pcregrep --version`, and what exactly means "didn't work"?

Comment: grep (GNU grep 2.7)

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`

```
awk -F'|' '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/([a-z]|[A-Z])+ /,"",$i); printf "%s",$i; if(i<NF) {printf "|"} else { printf "\n"}}}' foo
```

---

*Example*

```
% cat foo
cat dog AHF123432 | 123432 | dhfshfjdh
lion AFG23412 | 23412 | dfshjhfjdh

% awk -F'|' '{for (i=1; i<=NF;i++) {gsub(/([a-z]|[A-Z])+ /,"",$i); printf "%s",$i; if(i<NF) {printf "|"} else { printf "\n"}}}' foo
AHF123432 | 123432 | dhfshfjdh
AFG23412 | 23412 | dfshjhfjdh
```